# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

So I used Spring to developed a webapp on my local machine, and it works perfectly fine locally. Then I tried to deploy it, and I uploaded the .war file to my site.

I got the NoClassDefFoundError, here's the stack-trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonController' defined in file [/usr/local/shared/tomcat/kenendz/webapps/zzz/WEB-INF/classes/zzz/web/CommonController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.setClassLoader(PointcutParser.java:219)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.<init>(PointcutParser.java:205)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.getPointcutParserSupportingSpecifiedPrimitivesAndUsingSpecifiedClassLoaderForResolution(PointcutParser.java:167)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.initializePointcutParser(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:216)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:201)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:170)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:208)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 42 more
```

I do have aspectjweaver.jar and aspectjrt.jar in my classpath, and the webapp works on my local system.

**UPDATE**

I just find out that there's permission issues during deploying this webapp

```
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1382 ms
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'servlet': initialization started
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.profiles.active]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.profiles.active" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.profiles.active]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.profiles.active")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.profiles.default" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.profiles.default")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.profiles.default" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:39:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.profiles.default")
```

Comment: How did you "put it online"?

Comment: @Alfabravo Well.. I mean deploy it on my site, sorry

Comment: no problem. Maybe the WAR was built incorrectly. Check that the jars are in there.

Comment: Also check that you don't have two copies of the same jar (different versions).

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is pretty eloquent: the class just isn't there. Does the exception arise during the deploy or during a request? are you deploying to Tomcat or some other container?

Comment: @Alfabravo I double checked the lib folder, and there are aspectjrt and aspectjweaver, and no duplication

Comment: @emjay I chekced, there's no duplication

Comment: Depending on the web server/container you're using, different versions with significant changes might be loaded on default server libraries.

Comment: @EvilToad I thought this happened during request, but your question lead me to check whether this webapp is deployed successfully or not. Then I found there are permission issues when deploying

Comment: @Alfabravo I'm using Tomcat 7 as the container. And it turns out to be the problem with security

Comment: Good catch. Remember posting the process you follow when you manage to deploy them successfully and mark it as answer!

Comment: @Alfabravo Thank you all for the help, I will post the process after deploying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was the problem with request, but Evil Toad's question leads me to check whether the webapp is deployed successfully. And it turns out it's the problem with the security

Here is the catalina log produced by tomcat

```
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.profiles.active]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.profiles.active" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:29:59 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.profiles.active]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.profiles.active")
Aug 23, 2015 11:29:59 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.profiles.default" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:29:59 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.profiles.default")
Aug 23, 2015 11:29:59 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.profiles.default" "read")
Aug 23, 2015 11:29:59 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment getSystemAttribute
INFO: Caught AccessControlException when accessing system environment variable [spring.profiles.default]; its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.spring.profiles.default")
```

So I modified catalina.policy
added the following lines

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/webAppName/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

webAppName should be replaced with the webapp's name

Finally the webapp is deployed successfully, and it works!!